# How to write to add files to a zip archive using VB.NET code equivalent to VbScript?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

The following vbscript code adds the contents of a folder to a zip archive:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
folder = objArgs(0)
zip = objArgs(1)

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(zip, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(folder).Items
objShell.NameSpace(zip).CopyHere(source)

wScript.Sleep 5000
```

Yet when I try to use equivalent VB.NET code, I always end up with an empty zip document. What is the following code doing wrong?

```
Const folder As String = "C:\temp"
Const zip As String = "C:\output.zip"

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(zip, True).Write("PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & New String(Chr(65), 18).Replace(Chr(65), Chr(0))) 'New String(vbNullChar, 18))

Dim objShell As Object = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim source As Object = objShell.NameSpace(folder).Items
objShell.NameSpace(zip).CopyHere(source)

Sleep(5000)
```

...
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Integer)

Comment: [.NET 4.5 has the `ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110))

Answer (score 0):

In (vb).Net there is a really good library for writing to zip files.
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

```
Dim z As New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile("File name of zip file")
z.AddDirectory("Path to directory to add")
z.save()
```

Comment: It is a requirement that the code stays away from third party libraries. thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (.NET 2) or (.NET 4) then try (GZipStream): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

If you are using (.NET 4.5) then use (ZipArchive):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The flowing code works for me

Here is the original URL
     http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257193/Easily-Zip-Unzip-Files-using-Windows-Shell

Code:

```
Dim outputZip As String = "output zip file path"
Dim inputZip As String = "input zip file path"
Dim inputFolder As String = "input folder path"
Dim outputFolder As String = "output folder path"

'Declare the shell object
Dim shObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"))

Sub Zip()

    'Lets create an empty Zip File .
    'The following data represents an empty zip file.
    Dim startBytes() As Byte = {80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    'Data for an empty zip file.

    FileIO.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(outputZip, startBytes, False)
    'We have successfully created the empty zip file.

    'Declare the folder which contains the items (files/folders) that you want to zip.
    Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((inputFolder))

    'Declare the created empty zip file.
    Dim output As Object = shObj.NameSpace((outputZip))

    'Compress the items into the zip file.
    output.CopyHere((input.Items), 4)

End Sub
```

Regards